# Trying to get property of non-object, prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

Hello I am currently trying to connect my php file to a database but for some reason I keep getting this error returned to me Trying to get property of non-object. This appears to be a problem with the query its self as its coming from line 23 but I cannot for the life of me see the issue. Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include("dbconnect.php");
//get first 3 months
$month = '%'.$_POST['month'].'%';
//month 1 and 2 are currently not in use till issue is fixed
$month2 = '%'.$_POST['month'].'%';
$month3 = '%'.$_POST['month'].'%';
echo $month;

            //connect to database and prepare mysqli statement to get day, title, details, time and location if month has any details
            //will be adding more details for this statement to get once it is fully tested
            if($connect->connect_errno){
                printf("connection failed, please try again and if this error occurs again please submit this bug through the contact us page", $connect->connect_error);
                exit();
            }
            $CalendarDetails = $connect->prepare("SELECT `date`, `time`, `title`, `details`, `eventLocation`, `longitude`, `latitude` FROM `calendar` WHERE `date` LIKE ?");
            //$CalendarDetails = $connect->prepare("SELECT date, time, title, details, eventLocation, longitude, latitude FROM calendar WHERE date LIKE ?");
            //check if connection succeeded 
            //if ( false===$CalendarDetails ) {
                //error occurs in line below
            //  die('failed error 1 ' . htmlspecialchars($CalendarDetails->error));
            //}
            //bind the month to the prepared statement

            $CalendarDetails->bind_param("s", $month);
            //check if failed
            //if ( false===$CalendarDetails ) {
            //  die('failed error 2 ' . htmlspecialchars($CalendarDetails->error));
            //}
            //execute query
            $CalendarDetails->execute();
            //check if failed
            //if ( false===$CalendarDetails ) {
            //  die('failed error 3 ' . htmlspecialchars($CalendarDetails->error));
            //}
            //store results
            $CalendarDetails->store_result();
            //if ( false===$CalendarDetails ) {
            //  die('failed error 4 ' . htmlspecialchars($CalendarDetails->error));
            //}
            //bind results to separate variables
            $CalendarDetails->bind_result($date, $time, $title, $details, $time, $location, $longitude, $latitude);
            //get results

            if($day != null){
            if($month != null){
                //create an array to store results and send to app 
                //$Allevents = array();
                $i = 0;
                $event[$i] = array();
                while($CalendarDetails->fetch()){
                $j = strval($i);
                //this will combine all results into one string and will be split into an array in java
                $event[$j] = $date. "|". $title. "|". $details. "|". $time. "|". $location. "|". $longitude. "|". $latitude;
                /*$event['day'][$i] = $day;
                $event['title'][$i] = $title;
                $event['details'][$i] = $details;
                $event['time'][$i] = $time;
                $event['location'][$i] = $location;
                $event['longitude'][$i] = $longitude;
                $event['latitude'][$i] = $latitude;*/
                //$Allevents[$i] = $event;
                $i++;
                }


                echo json_encode($event);
                mysqli_stmt_close($CalendarDetails);    
            }else{
                echo "month not sent from app"; 
            }
            }else{
                echo "no events this month";
            }

?>
```

update with dbconnect file code

```
$connect= new mysqli("127.0.0.1",$config['username'],$password,$config['dbname'], 3306);
```

Update 2 I have commented out the if statements relating to the query and I now get a similar error on line 26 which is

```
$CalendarDetails->bind_param("s", $month);
```

The error I am now recieving is:
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Update 3
The reason my prepare statements failed was due to a spelling error, calendar in my database was spelled incorrectly.

Comment: `$event[$j] = $date + "|" + ...` those should be dots, and not plus signs.

Comment: "as its coming from line 20" - what's line 20?

Comment: thank you i will change that now, mixing php concatenation with java haha.

Comment: @FuzzyTree sorry i added some extra comments just before i uploaded Line 20 is now line 22, Ill fix that now.

Comment: Please put a comment so line 20 stands out from the others.

Comment: The only way that you get to that line is if `false===$CalendarDetails`, right? So how can you expect to do `$CalendarDetails->error`?

Comment: @noob I pasted your code to Sublime and line 20 is "//check if connection succeeded" so we still can not figure out where the error is ocurring. Also, could you copy the original error message?

Comment: @marcellorvalle just done that there.

Comment: @Patrick I don't quite understand what you are trying to say, I assumed that if the statement failed in some way it would give me an error which it did. Can you elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: Where are you defining your `$connect` variable? I don't see it. I assume it's under `dbconnect.php`?

Comment: @marcellorvalle this is coming from android studio so ignore the break rights and also its now line 23 after adding comments. <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Calendar.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />failed error 1

Comment: If `$CalendarDetails === false`, then you are effectively trying to do `false->error`, which definitely isn't going to work.

Comment: Ok! Check errors on your $connect object with $connect->error (after the $connect->prepare call) also take a look at Patrick's answer.

Comment: Please update your question and add the codes inside `dbconnect.php`.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio that is in a separate file coming from include("dbconnect.php");. There is no issue with this file as I am running multiple other php files using this

Comment: @PatrickQ well im not very good at php as im sure you can tell ha I have just seen this method being used before have you got any suggestions on retrieving errors on the issue

Comment: @noob You should _never_ _ever_ blindly copy/paste someone else's code that you do not completely understand. Not only is it unlikely to work the way that you want it to, but it can often introduce vulnerabilities that can leave you an easy target for attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit of code that is causing the error is this:  `$CalendarDetails->error`.  The only way to get to that, as dictated by your logic, is if this condition is met: `if ( false===$CalendarDetails )`.  That means that `$CalendarDetails` *is* `false`.  `false` is a boolean, and not an object.  So when you do `$CalendarDetails->error` (which is effectively translated to `false->error`), you are attempting to get a property (`error`) of a non-object (`false`).

Comment: No my logic was based on the fact that variables on php are dynamic in other words you do not need to declare their type so I assumed that if the query failed it would output a boolean rather than an object. Also I have no idea how to error check on php this is just what i found worked for other people. I have used this method before in other php files(examples of file are available if you want) and it never seemed to enter the if statement so I assumed it worked.

Comment: I will remove them from my file anyway,but  for now though Id like to know why its entering the if statement in the particular case and not in other cases which pretty much do the same thing.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer for people that may have a similar issue. While its not what was wrong with my file(why the prepare statement was failing) it was the question I actually asked (due to my own ignorance ha) you did explain it the issue asked perfectly thanks.